# Combined cql_filter for multiple layers in WMS request to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, cql-filter

Is there a way to combine same cql_filters for multiple layers?
The cql_filters are the same for most of the layers. The request is getting very long. To optimize it, it would be great to simplify things.

Some cql_filter parts are the same (create date filter, applications name, etc.). So it might work with an "over all layer" filter as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, each layer must have it's own filter. If you need to apply a filter sharing a common value across several layers you could probably use an environment variable into a series of SQL views.